How to load csv files into snowflake using rust script
I am trying to upload my csv file into snowflake using rust script using the PUT query command
let put_query = format!("PUT file://{} @{}", file_path, stage_name);

But I am getting the following error:
Error: Json(Error("missing field `parameters`", line: 7, column: 1), "{\n \"data\" : {\n \"errorCode\" : \"000002\",\n \"age\" : 0,\n \"sqlState\" : \"0A000\",\n \"queryId\" : \"01b93919-010b-c6e1-000a-676f00026426\"\n},\n \"code\" : \"000002\",\n \"message\" : \"Unsupported feature 'unsupported_requested_format:snowflake'.\",\n \"success\" : false,\n \"headers\" : null\n}") error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\connect_rust_snowflake.exe` (exit code: 1)

Not able to make what does the error conveys. I got the error when I am trying to read the csv file.
Some one please explain about it.
Thankyou
